# Facebook Marketing API Set action_attribution_windows No views

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When using the Facebook marketing api i would like to download the actions without the action_attribution_windows 1d_view option.

I currently use the following setup;

```
# Ad import fields
fields = [
    # Ad meta data
    Insights.Field.account_id,
    Insights.Field.account_name,
    Insights.Field.campaign_id,
    Insights.Field.campaign_name,
    Insights.Field.adset_id,
    Insights.Field.adset_name,
    Insights.Field.ad_id,
    Insights.Field.ad_name,
    Insights.Field.date_start,
    Insights.Field.date_stop,
    # Ad metrics
    Insights.Field.cpc,
    Insights.Field.cpm,
    Insights.Field.cpp,
    Insights.Field.ctr, 
    Insights.Field.impressions,
    Insights.Field.reach,
    Insights.Field.spend,
    Insights.Field.inline_link_clicks, 
    Insights.Field.clicks,
    Insights.Field.actions
     ]

# Ad parameters
params_ad = {
    'level': Insights.Level.ad, 
    'limit': limit if limit > 0 else None,
    'time_range': {
        'since': since,
        'until': until
    },
    'action_attribution_windows': ['28d_click'],
}

# Download data from Facebook
my_insights = my_account.get_insights(fields=fields, params=params_ad)
```

This however downloads the data as 28d_click with 1d_view. As i think it defaults at 1d_view when no value is given.

How would i disable the 1d_view?

Answer (score 0):

> How would i disable the 1d_view?

**You can't, you would need to specify the number of days if you use action_attribution_windows otherwise as you guessed, it would default to `1d_view`**

From the docs,
`action_attribution_windows` can be given custom day parameters as it is a:
    list

However you can specify `7d_view`, `28d_view` if you don't need `1d_view`.

> We measure the actions that occur when a conversion event occurs and look back in time 1-day, 7-days, and 28 days

Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.9

Please comment for more information.